# filtering products by categories [PROBLEM]

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django, react-native

I got a problem with filtering products by categories. My issue is I want to order my products by "category" as I've made in my JSON file. If a customer would click "Amulets" the page shows only products with category "Amulets".
[image]
[image]
[image]

How to do that? I guess I should to use "Filter" but I'm a beginner so I don't know how to. Thanks a lot for any help! much appreciate it!

I've tried to use product.filter but I can't ;/ thanks for help!

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Please see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

there is 2 ways:

- filtering on FE
- filtering on BE

---

in case of filtering in FE:

```
products.filter(x => x.category == selectedCategory)
```

Where the selectedCategory is state hold in useState -> which change in the UI interaction, which your user make with page.

in case of filtering in BE:

- BE needs to get request with **selectedCategory**.
- Filtering the data based on parameter passed by frontend.
- Return the amount of data - which comes from fronted.

then:

```
input_dict = json.loads(input_json)
filteredDate= [x for x in input_dict if x['category'] == selectedCategory]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I guess I messed up. That what I want to do is to take from my database based on SQLITE3 products dependencies on category. For example in my page "http://localhost:3000/d2r-ladder-items/amulets-ladder" I want to only show all products from database with category "amulets" nothing else. Thanks a lot for your answer! Appreciate it much!

Comment: So there is 3rd option - filter in 
API <-> Database layer

Comment: that's the way I think I guess It can be a gamechanger thanks a lot dude!